Пытаюсь сделать бота на python, который будет принимать ссылки на сайты, а отправлять в ответ скриншот этого сайта
Основная ошибка в том, что мой бот то не отвечает вообще на ссылку, то выдает ошибки по типу: WebDriver.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'  или Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Вот код:
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, Command_Handler, Message_Handler, Filters, Callback_Context
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from PIL import Image

# Функция для создания скриншота страницы
def capture_screenshot(url):
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome64_55.0.2883.75\\chrome.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('http://google.com/')
    driver.quit()
    return screenshot_path

    # Настройка драйвера
    with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        screenshot_path = "screenshot.png"
        driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
    return screenshot_path

# Обработчик сообщений с ссылкой
def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    url = update.message.text
    if url.startswith("http://") or url.startswith("https://"):
        try:
            # Создаем скриншот
            screenshot_path = capture_screenshot(url)

            # Отправляем скриншот в ответ
            with open(screenshot_path, 'rb') as photo:
                update.message.reply_photo(photo)

            # Удаляем скриншот после отправки
            os.remove(screenshot_path)
        except Exception as e:
            update.message.reply_text(f"Не удалось создать скриншот. Ошибка: {e}")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Пожалуйста, отправьте корректную ссылку на веб-сайт.")

# Стартовая команда
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text("Привет! Отправь мне ссылку, и я сделаю скриншот страницы для тебя.")

# Основная функция
def main():
    TOKEN = "7858227532:AAF0f1uKLJQS0RVzvBGeKnfKFa9PBq3-JSw"
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    # Регистрация обработчиков
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_message))

    # Запуск бота
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

